# Oracle Dependency Between Schemas

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

We have a database with multiple schemas. The various schemas have dependencies among themselves.

The dependencies include:

```
- PK/FK relationships
- Triggers which record DML activity in separate audit schema
- Views accessing other tables via DBLINK.
```

Whenever we want to do maintenance, we want to be sure that all dependencies have been taken care of. Otherwise - we end up in issues such as PK/FK issues, INVALID objects.

Are there tools or scripts which can be used to compose some kind of dependency tree ?

Comment: Not sure why maintenance would cause any corruption of primary keys.  We have objects that randomly seem to go invalid after a gather schema stats or other causes.  We created an alert that monitors for invalid objects.  When it triggers we go an manually recompile the objects.  In some cases even Oracle support could not determine the why an object had become invalid.

Comment: to clarify - by maintenance we mean dropping a schema or refreshing a schema. Naturally when two schemas are related and one is dropped, it will create issues in other dependent schema.

Comment: Are you just looking for a query against `dba_dependencies`?

Comment: @AlexPoole  - yes, DBA_DEPENDENCIES is one way to get that information. In addition, if a stored proc has query which accesses data over DB_LINK, I need to know about that stored proc also.

Comment: Doesn't the `referenced_link_name` give you that info?

Comment: sure it does. What I am looking for is some kind of  "Impact Analysis" tools or scripts which can provide "one-stop" information for such dependencies.

Comment: The only "tools" I've seen similar to this are roll-your-own SQL statements. To get exactly what you want you're probably going to have to start coding this up yourself.

Comment: @BobJarvis - yeah, I guessed so. Just trying avoid "re-inventing a wheel"